# Explicit computation of induced modules of semidirect products with the symmetric group

Tags: rt.representation-theory, co.combinatorics, symmetric-groups

I've gotten stuck in a project I have been working on, essentially on the following combinatorial question about the symmetric group.

One can obtain a 1-dimensional representation $M^n_c$ of the algebra $T_n := S_n \rtimes \mathbb{C}[y_1, \dots, y_n] $ by letting each $y_i$ act by $c$ and $S_n$ act trivially.
Given a partition $\pi$ of $n  =n_1 + \dots + n_k$ and $c_1, \dots, c_k \in \mathbb{C}$, we can consider the standard induced module
$$ M^{\pi}_c = \mathrm{Ind} ( M^{n_1}_{c_1} \otimes \dots \otimes M^{n_k}_{c_k}) $$
where the induction is from the subalgebra $T_{n_1} \otimes \dots \otimes T_{n_k} \subset T_n$ to $T_n$.

As far as I know, the simple quotients of these standard modules form a complete class for the simple representations of $T_n$.  (I think this is a general fact about semidirect products of a finite group with a commutative algebra, together with the fact that representations of the symmetric group $S_n$ can be obtained by taking quotients induction of the trivial representation of a Young subgroup $S_{n_1} \times \dots \times S_{n_k}$.)

My question is how to represent this explicitly in terms of the simple objects in the semisimple category $Rep(S_n)$.  First of all, the $S_n$-module $M^{\pi}_c$ can be described in a combinatorial manner in terms of the simple objects in $Rep(S_n)$ using the Kostka numbers.  The action of the $y_i$'s on $M^{\pi}_c$ can be given in terms of a suitable morphism $y: \mathfrak{h} \otimes M^{\pi}_c \to M^{\pi}_c$, where $\mathfrak{h} \in Rep(S_n)$ is the regular representation.

The Pieri rule allows one to compute the decomposition in irreducibles (as parametrized by Young diagrams, of course) of $\mathfrak{h} \otimes M^{\pi}_c $, so we can view $y$ as a bunch of matrices based upon this decomposition (matrices w.r.t. the simple objects in $Rep(S_n)$, not as vector spaces).

Is there an approach  to compute these matrices?

I am interested in this because it may allow a way to directly interpolate the construction of these modules to complex rank, via Pavel Etingof's [program](http://www.newton.ac.uk/programmes/ALT/seminars/032716301.html).  (I believe one can interpolate the construction in another way, by reasoning more directly on the definition of the category $Rep(S_t)$ given by Deligne, but this seems to be useless as far as explicit computations--which might be helpful to study the "degeneracy phenomena" that Etingof has suggested might exist--are concerned.) In this case we have tensor categories $Rep(S_t)$ for $t$ not necessarily an integer, and while the interpretation in terms of vector spaces fails, the one in terms of Young diagrams does not.

**Edit** (12/27) I added a bounty today and here is some additional information that may be useful:

It should come out that the matrices representing the $y$-morphism $\mathfrak{h} \otimes M^{\pi}_c \to M^{\pi}_c$ are polynomials in the dimension $n$.  When increasing $n$, we change the partition $\pi$ by adding to the first (largest) element and leaving the rows below fixed.  Since a simple object in $Rep(S_t)$ for $t$ not an integer can be represented as a normal Young diagram (of size, say, $N$) with a "very long line" of "size" $t-N$ at the top, this kind of a polynomial interpolation will allow for an interpolation of the $M^{\pi}_c$ to complex rank.  My claim that it should come out as a polynomial was based upon studying induction directly on these categories and finding it was interpolable.  However, I don't know how to compute the $y$'s directly as matrices via the simple object decomposition.
My hope was that there is a clean not-too-computationally-intensive way to do this, but unfortunately I'm not yet sufficiently comfortable with the theory of the symmetric group to have any ideas as to how to proceed.

I am also interested in the degenerate affine Hecke algebra of type A, where these kinds of standard induced modules can be defined similarly.  Their simple quotients form a complete collection of irreducible modules for the Hecke algebra according to a theorem of Zelevinsky, and I know that these, too, can be interpolated by reasoning on the definitions in Deligne's paper (so one gets objects in the interpolated category $Rep(H_t)$, which is defined in Etingof's talk).  But I am curious here too how it is possible to compute the $y$-morphisms as matrices using the decomposition into irreducibles in $Rep(S_t)$.

Comment: Hi Akhil, this is an interesting question.  I have some thoughts on it but I am going to take a few days before I post an answer so I can be clear.  In the meantime, am I correct that M_c^\pi, as a representation of S_n, is isomorphic to Ind^{S_n}_{S_\pi}(C), or in other words C[S_n] / C[S_\pi]?  Then the y_i act on this representation?  This seems to follow from the fact that the subalgebra T_\pi is really S_{\pi}C[Y] (right?).  I just want to make sure I haven't confused the setup.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  (I assume in Ind^{S_n}_{S_\pi}(C), C refers to the trivial representation of S_\pi.)  I think you're also right about the subalgebra T_\pi being S_\pi C[Y] (i.e. the image in T_n, or intrinsically S_\pi \rtimes C[Y]).  The statement is also true for the dAHA case, though it requires the analog of the PBW theorem for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect I know the answer, but I don't yet have a proof (not because I think it would be hard to prove, but because I didn't try really; when you see my guess, you'll likely want to believe it).  The answer is stated not in the basis of simples, because I didn't compute the decomposition of $\mathbb{C}[S_n/S_{pi}]$. However, it is stated in the tensor category S_n-mod, so that given that decomposition, you can easily adjust what I write here.

> **Fact:** Let H be a finite dimensional semi-simple Hopf algebra (e.g. H=\mathbb{C}[S_n]), and let $V\in H$-mod be an irrep.  Let us regard H as an H-module via the left action.  Then $V\otimes H\cong H^{\oplus dim(V)}$.

The proof of this fact is given as follows (see http://www-math.mit.edu/~etingof/tenscat.pdf, or Akhil's comments below):

$Hom_H(V\otimes H,W)=Hom_H(H,^\ast V\otimes W) = \widetilde{^\ast V\otimes W}$

On the other hand, $Hom_H(\tilde{V}\otimes H,W) =  \tilde{V}\otimes Hom_H(H,W) = \widetilde{V\otimes W}$,

where $\tilde{M}$ means we forget the module $M$ down to a vector space, which we use as a multiplicity space (just because the direct sum decomposition I asserted originally isn't canonically given, you just know that there's this multiplicity space)

(above we took right duals since I didn't assume $H$ is commutative or co-commutative; for $C[G]$ there is no need to distinguish.)  One could (and should) be uncomfortable that we got duals on the one hand and not on the other.  However, the standard representation for $S_n$ is special in that it is isomorphic to its own dual, by sending $e_i$ to $e^i$ (the point is that the standard rep for $S_n$ has a basis build into its definition).

The general fact above about Hopf algebras is used to relate Frobenius-Perron dimension for representations of Hopf algebras to ordinary dimension of the underlying vector space; indeed the regular representation is the unique eigenvector which realizes the Frobenius Perron dimension as an eigenvalue.

Okay so now we are considering $\mathfrak{h}\otimes \mathbb{C}[S_n/S_{\pi}]\to \mathbb{C}[S_n/S_{\pi}]$.  This is then isomorphic to $(\mathfrak{h}\otimes \mathbb{C}[S_n])\otimes_{S_\pi}\mathbf{1}$, where we tensor the trivial $S_\pi$-module on the right.  This is because $C[S_n]$ is a $S_n-S_\pi$ bi-module, so that the map
$\mathfrak{h}\otimes \mathbb{C}[S_n] \to \mathfrak{h}\otimes \mathbb{C}[S_n/S_\pi]$ given by right multiplying with the symmetrizer $a_\pi=\sum_{g\in S_\pi} g$ is an $S_n$-morphism, and allows us to identify $\mathfrak{h}\otimes \mathbb{C}[S_n]\otimes_{S_\pi}\mathbf{1}$ with $\mathfrak{h}\otimes \mathbb{C}[S_\pi]$.
Morally, this is just because $S_\pi$ acts on the right, while the other action is on the left.

[edited an error from preceding paragraph]

Together with the Fact, this implies that $\mathfrak{h}\otimes \mathbb{C}[S_n/S_\pi]$ is in fact just isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[S_n/S_\pi]^{\oplus dim(\mathfrak{h})},$ which I should really write as 
$\mathbb{C}[S_n/S_\pi]\otimes \tilde{\mathfrak{h}^\ast}$.

Well, now we have this function $c: \mathfrak{h}\to \mathbb{C}$.  We will project $\mathbb{C}[S_n/S_\pi]^{\oplus dim(\mathfrak{h})}$ (or rather $\mathbb{C}[S_n/S_\pi]\otimes \tilde{\mathfrak{h}}$) to $\mathbb{C}[S_n/S_\pi]$ by just applying $c$ to the multiplicity space.

I haven't really proved that this last paragraph is what happens, but once one has applied "Fact" above, this seems like the only natural guess.  I imagine verifying it would be pretty straightforward.

Note that it doesn't seem to matter how $\mathbb{C}[S_n/S_{\pi}]$ decomposes into simples, since they all get lumped together.

Comment: Thanks for the response! 

I do have a few questions.  I thought about the result you mentioned about Hopf algebras, taking $H = C[G]$ for $G$ a finite group.  
Then if $V$ is a nontrivial irreducible representation of $G$ and $W$ is any representation, $Hom_G(C[G] \otimes V, W) \simeq Hom_G(C[G], V^{\vee} \otimes W) \simeq V^{\vee} \otimes W$.  Also $Hom_G( C[G]^{\oplus dim(V)}, W) \simeq W^{\oplus dim(V)}$.  I don't think these are isomorphic as $G$-modules.  

I'll add another comment for the other question I had because of the 500-character limit.


Comment: Actually I answered the other question myself.  I'm just a bit confused about why $\mathfrak{h} \otimes C[S_n/S_\pi]$ is isomorphic to $C[S_n/S_\pi]^{dim(\mathfrak{h})}$.

Comment: Actually Akhil, I think you have provided the proof of the "Fact" I mentioned.  Note that Hom spaces aren't representations, but rather they are just vector spaces.

When you write $Hom_G(C[G],V^\vee\otimes W)\cong V^\vee\otimes W$, you mean as a vector space (this is true, as such a map is determined by where 1 goes).  As a vector space, $V^\vee\otimes W\cong W^{\oplus dim(V)}$, as I claimed.  So you have proven the "fact".

Comment: I found a reference for you, from some of Pavel's notes:  http://www-math.mit.edu/~etingof/tenscat.pdf page 81.  Note that the proof is the same as the one you proposed.

Comment: I'll edit the post to include the new information.

Comment: Ok, yes, I see what you mean.  I confused $Hom_G$ with the $G$-representation $Hom_C$.  Thanks for the reference!  Now I this makes more sense (I'll look at it again and comment later).

Comment: I noticed another way to prove the fact above for finite groups: it is implied by the character of the regular representation.  Also, I found an explicit decomposition for $\mathfrak{h} \otimes C[S_n]$.  There is a $S_n$-homomorphism from $\mathfrak{h} \otimes C[S_n]$ to $n$ copies of the trivial representation sending $k \otimes \sigma$ to $\sigma^{-1}(k)$.  Now I am going to look into proving that what you described is the right action.

Comment: Sorry, I had another question.  I didn't quite understand the part about where you claim that $(\mathfrak{h} \otimes C[S_n] )\otimes_{S_\pi} 1 $ is isomorphic to $C[S_n/S_\pi]^{\oplus dim(h)}$.  It is true that $\mathfrak{h} \otimes C[S_n]$ is isomorphic as a $S_n$-module to $C[S_n]^{\oplus dim(h)}$.  But I don't think the isomorphism preserves the right action of $S_\pi$.
For instance, if we use the decomposition in the previous comment, then we split into $T_k$, where $T_k$ is generated by $a \otimes \sigma$ for $\sigma^{-1}(a) = k$.  Right multiplication by $S_\pi$ doesn't preserve $T_\pi$

Comment: I was thinking though that we still do get some kind of a deomposition. I think it has to do with the orbits of $S_\pi$ on $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ (i.e. the initial partition). Each $T_k$ as defined in the previous comment gets sent by right multiplication by $\tau \in S_\pi$ to $T_{\tau^{-1}(k)}$. So each of the $T_k$ for $k$ belonging to one block get identified. Also, there is some quotienting in each $T_k$ (isomorphic to $C[S_n]$) because there will be $\tau$'s that fix $k$. For these $\tau$, $(a \otimes \sigma) \tau = a  \otimes \sigma \tau$ maps to $\sigma \tau$ under 

Comment: the isomorphism $T_k \to C[S_n]$ mapping $a \otimes \sigma \to \sigma$.  So each $T_k$ should get quotiented out by anything of the form $\sigma \tau - \tau$ for $\tau \in S_\pi, \tau(k)=k$.  Am I missing something here?  Perhaps it's possible to compute the $y$-action in terms of these blocks, but it would appear to be significantly different from what you described above.

Comment: (I deleted a comment that answered a question I realized you weren't asking =]).  In "I noticed another way..." it seems that "trivial representation" should be replaced by "left regular representation", right?  The explicit decomposition you wrote is surely useful.  Do you mean $k\times\sigma\maptso (\sigma,\sigma^{-1}(k)), that is it sends \sigma [Okay my wife is giving me a hard time for writing math on New Years.  More tomorrow.]

Comment: Akhil,  you're definitely right and I was definitely wrong in my conjecture.  I had remembered the decomposition of $V\otimes C[S_n]$ without remembering the specifics, and you're correct that right multiplication by the projector $a_\pi$, while still a morphism, simply doesn't preserve the isotypic components.  I'm not sure how to correct my statement now.

Comment: Thanks anyway for your help!  This definitely got me thinking quite a bit in the right direction about the symmetric group.  Let me see if I can find something.

Comment: Sure; you do seem to be on the right track with your corrections; let me know if you come to a conclusion.  By the way, feel free to email me about your project (you can find my email at math.mit.edu) if other things come up.  I'm definitely interested in what you're up to.  I think also Noah Snyder would be another good person to talk to; he's a post-doc at Columbia who knows a good deal about tensor categories and RepS_t.